# Vertical alignment of elements whilst using css-float

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

Why won't three elements on the same line get vertically aligned at the same height when using floats?

It appears this is browser specific: the layout is broken in Gecko (Firefox), the right elements is placed on a separate line, whilst the layout is fine in Chromium.

HTML markup:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <a class="left" href="left">left</a>
        <a class="center" href="center">center</a>
        <a class="right" href="right">right</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS styles:

```
div{width: 100%;margin: 20px 0; }
div p{width: 100%; white-space: nowrap; text-align: center;border: 1px solid blue;}
a.left{float: left;}
a.center{}
a.right{float: right;}
```

This is the layout result in FireFox: 
[image]

For convenience: take a look at this [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/R3qDF/1/).

I know I have seen this problem before, but I just pull my hair and cannot find a solution for this!

Comment: @Paulie_D Ok, it appears to be browser specific. The right element ist placed on a separate line when using Firefox. I will update the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it appears that there is a very simple workaround that actually "just works" for me. I post it as a question since I did not receive any (usable) answer for such a basic question.

The layout is fine in Gecko (Firefox) when the right element is placed *before* the center element in the html markup:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <a class="left" href="left">left</a>
        <a class="right" href="right">right</a>
        <a class="center" href="center">center</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

I have no idea why this logic applies, but I am convinced that the Mozilla people will have perfect reasons why this behaviour is just right...

Comment: The problem goes away if you remove the `white-space: nowrap;` on the `p` tag. Also not sure why :)